# How do I grab data content from a group of tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have an outer div, lets call it `#outerdiv`. Inside of #outerdiv is a group of `<a>` tags. These tags are asynchronously generated and will be tested for content after the user presses a button. None of the `<a>` tags are children of each other, they are all children of #outerdiv. Each `<a>` has an attribute called `data-content`, and each is equal to a number. Also inside each `<a>` tag is another div, which has a bunch of classes. Some of these tags have a specific class called `.active` inside it. I only want the `data-content` of tags with the `.active` class descendent. I want to take them and put them in an array or something simple. So here's an example:

```
<div id = "outerdiv" > 
    <a data-content = "1">
        <div class="classX active"></div>
    </a>
    <a data-content = "2">
        <div class="classX"></div>
    </a>
    <a data-content = "3">
        <div class="classX"></div>
    </a>
    <a data-content = "4">
        <div class="classX"></div>
    </a>
    <a data-content = "5">
        <div class="classX active"></div>
    </a>

</div>
```

So I just want the data-content of `1` and `5`.

So far, I know I can use .on to check asynchronous tags and .data("content") to grab data content. I'm thinking a for loop that checks the content inside my `#outerdiv`, but I don't exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need selector `#outerdiv a div.active` to get the innermost divs, then get their parent:

```js
var $aTags = $('#outerdiv a div.active').parent();
$aTags.each(function(i,a) {
  console.log($(a).attr('data-content'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerdiv">
  <a data-content="1">
    <div class="classX active"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="2">
    <div class="classX"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="3">
    <div class="classX"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="4">
    <div class="classX"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="5">
    <div class="classX active"></div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Think you can explain what $aTags is/does?

Comment: Also, it isn't working for me. Note, my <a> tags were created asynchronously using javascript and isn't in the main html page.

Comment: @munchschair, run it in the `onSuccess` callback of your asynchronous call?

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this is very easy using JQuery.

```js
var elements = [];
var $data = $('.classX.active').closest('a');
for(var i = 0; i < $data.length; i++){
    var value = $($data[i]).attr('data-content');
    elements.push(value);
}
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerdiv">
  <a data-content="1">
    <div class="classX active"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="2">
    <div class="classX"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="3">
    <div class="classX"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="4">
    <div class="classX"></div>
  </a>
  <a data-content="5">
    <div class="classX active"></div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can simply select all the active elements first using $(".active"), then you can chain the parents method to grab all the anchor parents element of every single active element. See [jQuery Api](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) for parents. So you can use $(".active").parents("a") to get all the parents. You can also add a more descriptive class here to avoid getting higher level parents. After you have the list of parents, you can simply iterate through the list and get the data elements use [Data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)